# How do I change the amount of memory flash can use in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I've noticed that when I load many flash videos, when flash uses too much memory to store the videos, the flash player crashes on all tabs:

> The following plug-in has crashed : Shockwave Flash

Can I increase the amount of memory flash can use ?

Comment: Right Click on the video, change the settings, but there is going to be a limit to how much memory flash will be able to use depending on your system.

Comment: If I `right click video` > `folder icon`, it says: `how much information youtube.com can store on your computer ?` I think this is local storage, and it's not used for storing video. 

If I go `right click video` > `global settings` > `local storage settings by site`, i have a list with with storages not exeeding the kilobyte. So I don't think it is used to store the video neither. Tell me if i'm wrong.